# how to change the design of product view page to 2columns-right in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I want to change the design of my product view page to 2columns-right. For that I changed in app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/catalog.xml to 2columns-right.
The code is

```
<reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
```

After clearing the cache also,design is not changing it is still in 2columns-left panel.
In admin also, set no to apply to products,then also it is not changing.

If anyone have any idea to change the design in 2columns-left for detail page, then please help me.
Thanks!

Comment: in which handler did you put this code ?

Comment: under this
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: no its not working....it still in 2columns-left design after clearing the cache also

Comment: @PrinceKumar Check weather the product has custom design in admin panel.

Answer (score 1):

create a `local.xml` file in layout directory and put this code inside it

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
          <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
           </reference> 
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: Any another solution for this which will help me to solve this problem

Comment: your location seems wrong . local.xml should reside here `app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/local.xml` (provided your current theme should be `default/mytheme`)

Comment: I put local.xml page in app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/ directory then also it is not working